# CodenameOne Connection Request hangs when repeated

Tags: connection, request, codenameone

I have the following Codename One code for accessing a network resource. It is almost an exact copy of the Codename One tutorial for this use case.

```
 public void executeRequest(){
    String url = "http://www.random.net";
    InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
    final Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();

    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
                //handle changes to my form
            }

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input)
                throws IOException {
              //handle parsing data
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
            super.handleIOException(err);
        }



    };
    r.setUrl(url);
    r.setPost(false);
    r.addArgument("arg", "2");
    r.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(r);

}
```

The first time I run it - no problem. If I try to "refresh" my data by calling the same method over again, the app will hang up with the InfiniteProgress dialog spinning forever. Its almost like the first network request is not ever really completing, and then the second one kind of conflicts. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, what fixed this for me was to use

NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);

instead. That cleared up most of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

By default duplicate requests to the exact same URL are disabled, try invoking `setDuplicatesSuppotred(true)` on the connection request.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Shai. I added that bit of code (reflected in my code block above) and tried it - same result. After adding the connection request to the queue, the app will hang and the ReadResponse method never gets called.

Comment: Do you send the second call before the first one finishes?
If so it might finish and go back to the waiting dialog of the previous call.
If not I suggest opening the Network Monitor tool to see the connections going out. You can also run in the debugger and press pause when the app is stuck to see where it is stuck for the various threads.

Answer (score 0):

I stucked with the same problem and none of solutions worked. However, I did it this way:

```
final NetworkManager nm = NetworkManager.getInstance();
nm.setTimeout(3000);
```

then

```
protected void postResponse() {
...
    nm.shutdown();
}
```

and call was made as
`nm.addToQueueAndWait(request);`

Maybe the fact that NetworkManager was made final did the job, but I put "shutdown" just for sure. It worked for me